Divergence of box diagrams in non-chiral Yukawa theory
I am strudying the following Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{m^{2}}{2}\phi^{2}+\overline{\psi}(i\phi-m_{F})\psi-ig\overline{\psi}\psi\phi.$$
More precisely, the $\phi\phi\longrightarrow\phi\phi$ process. Whose diagram is a box diagram.
My professor said that the process should be convergent without loop corrections, but every article studying this process says it diverges. I also calculated the amplitude myself and it diverges.
Anyone knows what is the real result?

Hi, we are working in 4 dimensions.

Which every article? Which page?

For examplo, David Tong lectures om QFT https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html, or this notes of Berkeley university http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/Yukawa.pdf.

So there is no tree diagram for your process.

Hi Ander Urtiaga. 1. Sounds like your professor should clarity their comment. 2. Hitoshi Murayama's notes are about pseudo-scalar Yukawa theory; not scalar Yukawa theory.
